# Javascript: Tabs in an searchsystem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well I need a bit help here, i just dont get how i can manage to make that script dynamic.
I like to press one continent, and it opens the correct land - then from the land it should open the correct region -> And from there it should open the correct city.
Also it shouldn't try to open one, if this continent/land/region has no child-> no another tab.

Its my part of an search engine. The Php and HTML doesent need to be shown here, it works right.

I like to make an Tab system with that i could close every box, beside the first one.
That should be the box that contains the continents.
From there you select one point from that box, in example Europa. Then the box that contains the lands from Europa should be visible. Then you can again select the next step, here in example you select now in the second box Europa->Spain Then it should open the box with the content of spain and so on.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#select_land_1').click(function(){
            $('.box_land').hide();
            $('.box_region').hide();
            $('.box_city').hide();
            $('#land_1').show();
            $('#select_region_12').click(function(){
                $('#region_12').show();
                $('#select_city_34').click(function(){
                    $('#city_34').show();
                });
                $('#select_city_35').click(function(){
                    $('#city_35').show();
                });
            });
        });
```

The Css looks like that :
http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/1479/bildnr1error.jpg

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: "That script"?  Dynamic?  "Press one continent"?  How is it that you suppose we're supposed to have any idea what you're talking about?

Comment: I have edit the text, so it should be easyer to understand

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
        $('.box_land'+'#land_1').show();
```

is weird and almost certainly not what you want. You didn't post any HTML, but perhaps you want just:

```
        $('#land_1').show();
```

Same for the other one.

Comment: well i have edit the whole text for an better understanding what i like to do. Thank you very much.